# Analysing Trends and spotting abnormal behaviour

Tags: python, mysql, database, analytics

I am creating a system for logging data from sensors. (Just a series of numbers)

I would like to be able to put the system into a "learn" mode for a couple of days so it can see what its "normal" operational values are and that once it is out of this any deviation from this behaviour past a certain point can be flagged.  The data is all stored in a MySQL database.

Any suggestions on how to carry this out would be welcome, as would locations for further reading on the topic.

I would preferably like to use python for this task.

The data temperature and humidity values ever 5 minutes in a temperature controlled area that is accessed and used during the day. This means the it will have fluctuations for when it is in use and some temperature changes. But anything different to this such as cooling or heating systems failing needs to be detected

Comment: Ca you give some details as to what you'll be recording? Continuous values? A single value or a set of them? How frequent will the measurements of behaviour be taken, and roughly what sort of unit will you be testing for abnormality?

Comment: The data temperature and humidity values ever 5 minutes in a temperature controlled area that is accessed and used during the day.  This means the it will have fluctuations for when it is in use and some temperature changes.  But anything different to this such as cooling or heating systems failing needs to be detected.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you should be looking at is [density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_estimation): the task of determining a model of how some variables behave, so that you can look for deviations from it.

Here's some *very* simple example code. I've assumed that temperature and humidity have independent normal distributions on their untransformed scales:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.mlab import normpdf
from itertools import izip

class TempAndHumidityModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tempMu=0
        self.tempSigma=1
        self.humidityMu=0
        self.humiditySigma=1

    def setParams(self, tempMeasurements, humidityMeasurements, quantile):
        self.tempMu=np.mean(tempMeasurements)
        self.tempSigma=np.std(tempMeasurements)
        self.humidityMu=np.mean(humidityMeasurements)
        self.humiditySigma=np.std(humidityMeasurements)

        if not 0 < quantile <= 1:
            raise ValueError("Quantile for threshold must be between 0 and 1")

        self._thresholdDensity(quantile, tempMeasurements, humidityMeasurements)

    def _thresholdDensity(self, quantile, tempMeasurements, humidityMeasurements):
        tempDensities = np.apply_along_axis(
            lambda x: normpdf(x, self.tempMu, self.tempSigma),0,tempMeasurements)
        humidityDensities = np.apply_along_axis(
            lambda x: normpdf(x, self.humidityMu, self.humiditySigma),0,humidityMeasurements)

        densities = sorted(tempDensities * humidityDensities, reverse=True)
        #Here comes the massive oversimplification: just choose the
        #density value at the quantile*length position, and use this as the threshold
        self.threshold = densities[int(np.round(quantile*len(densities)))]

    def probOfObservation(self, temp, humidity):
        return normpdf(temp, self.tempMu, self.tempSigma) * \
               normpdf(humidity, self.humidityMu, self.humiditySigma)

    def isNormalMeasurement(self, temp, humidity):
        return self.probOfObservation(temp, humidity) > self.threshold

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Create some simulated data
    temps = np.random.randn(100)*10 + 50
    humidities = np.random.randn(100)*2 + 10

    thm = TempAndHumidityModel()
    #going to hard code in the 95% threshold
    thm.setParams(temps, humidities, 0.95) 

    #Create some new data from same dist and see how many false positives
    newTemps = np.random.randn(100)*10 + 50
    newHumidities = np.random.randn(100)*2 + 10

    numFalseAlarms = sum(~thm.isNormalMeasurement(t,h) for t,h in izip(newTemps,newHumidities))
    print '{} false alarms!'.format(numFalseAlarms)

    #Now create some abnormal data: mean temp drops to 20
    lowTemps = np.random.randn(100)*10 + 20
    normalHumidities = np.random.randn(100)*2 + 10

    numDetections = sum(~thm.isNormalMeasurement(t,h) for t,h in izip(lowTemps,normalHumidities))
    print '{} abnormal measurements flagged'.format(numDetections)
```

Example output:

```
>> 3 false alarms!
>> 77 abnormal measurements flagged
```

Now, I have no idea whether the assumption of normality is appropriate for your data (you may want to transform the data onto a different scale so that it is); it's probably wildly inaccurate to assume independence between temperature and humidity; and the trick that I have used to find the density value corresponding to the requested quantile of the distribution should be replaced by something that uses the inverse CDF of the distribution. However, this should give you a flavour of what to do.

Note additionally that there are many good non-parametric density estimators: [kernel density estimators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) immediately spring to mind. These may be more appropriate if your data doesn't look like any standard distribution.

Comment: I am gonna have to get my statistics text book out. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to perform [anomaly detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) but your description of your data is vague.  You should start by trying to define/constrain what it means, in general, for your data to be "normal".

1. Is there a different "normal" for each sensor?
2. Is a sensor measurement somehow dependent on it's previous measurement(s)?
3. Does "normal" change over the course of a day?
4. Can the "normal" measurements from a sensor be characterized by a statistical model (e.g., are the data Gaussian or log-normal)?

Once you have answered those types of questions, then you can train a classifier or anomaly detector with a batch of data from your database and use the result to assess future log output.  If machine learning algorithms are applicable to your data, you might consider using [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/).  For statistical models, you could use the `stats` subpackage of [SciPy](https://scipy.org/). And, of course, for any kind of numerical data manipulation in python, [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) is your friend.